# fcitx not work on emacsclient --create-frame

Tags: linux, emacs

emacs --version:24.4.1
emacsclient --version:24.4
fcitx --version:4.2.8.5
uname -a:Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
gnome-ternimal --version:3.14.1

1.In gnome-ternimal,

```
$ emacs -q --daemon
$ emacsclient -c   # fcitx available in new frame
```

2.add emacs daemon to crontab
`$ crontab -e -u user1`

```
@reboot emacs -q -daemon
```

In gnome-terminal,

```
$ emacsclient -c    #fcitx NOT work in new frame
```

3.In terminal,fcitx is AVAILABLE,including `emacsclient -t`.

4.In GUI applications,fcitx is also AVAILABLE,such as emacs from emacs24.desktop, libreoffice, chrome.

Comment: The question is not program related, please ask on SuperUser

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's done.

Answer (score 1):

Must add im env to crontab emacs task,just like:

```
@reboot XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx" emacs --deamon 1 2>/dev/null
```